# What is the equivalent pixel format of SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ABGR1555 in OPENGL for a texture?

Tags: opengl, format, pixel, sdl-2, opengl-3

I have a game that outputs color value of type ABGR1555 to a frame buffer, and uptill now I was using SDL2 for the graphics(draws a texture) and it conveniently had an option to deal with the color format(SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ABGR1555) but I've recently moved to opengl 3 and it all seems to be going well except that I'm having trouble making opengl interpret the color values in the form of ABGR1555 when I'm trying to render the texture.

This is what I've tried so far and it isn't working and I'm not sure what I should do

```
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES, GL_TRUE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB5_A1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_1_5_5_5, texture);
```

I want opengl to interpret the color values in the frame buffer as ABGR1555, i.e I want the equivalent of SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ABGR1555 and I'm not sure how to get there. I would greatly appreciate help on this

Comment: `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_1_5_5_5` doesn't exist, perhaps you were thinking of `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1`?  Or `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_1_5_5_5_REV`.

Comment: Also, edit in a [mcve] to demonstrate the "isn't working".

Comment: `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_1_5_5_5_REV` is most likely what you want, but without `GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES`. The internal pixel format `GL_RGB5_A1` is ok.

Comment: @YakovGalka it still doesn't work

Comment: @genpfault a minimal reproducible example of what exactly? that's all there is for the color format